# Get numbers from vue array

Tags: vue.js

I have array with 12 month:

```
<ul >
    <li v-for="item, index in 12">
      <b :class="{'rounded-l-lg': index == 0, 'rounded-r-lg': index == 11}"></b>
      <span >{{ index + 1 }} Monat<span v-if="index != 0">e</span></span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And i have json file, In which there are numbers.

```
"sell": [
  {
    "id": 3,
    "caption": "GRATIS",
    "tooltip": "Lagerflächen von 0,5 m² bis 18 m²"
  },
  {
    "id": 12,
    "caption": "GRATIS",
    "tooltip": "Geräumiger Lastenaufzug"
  }
],
```

How can I collapse numbers? And if `index == json.sell.id` then show `{{ json.sell.caption }}`?

Comment: I don't understand your problem. Are you having problem reading from a json file?

Comment: collapse numbers  - please add example - Like "price: 5" need to change to "5.0 $" and ideas like this. No way to guess the output you want related to your data. Maybe related: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/filters.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
<template>
  <ul >
    <li v-for="item in 12">
      <b :class="{'rounded-l-lg': item == 1, 'rounded-r-lg': item == 12}"></b>
      <span >{{ item }}</span> Monat<span v-if="item > 1">e</span>
      {{ sales[item].caption }}
    </li>
  </ul>
</template>

<script>
import json from './file.json';

export default
{
  computed:
  {
    sales()
    {
      const result = {};
      (json.sell || []).forEach(item =>
      {
        result[item.id] = item;
      });
      return result;
    }
  }
}
</script>
```